# HttpTestingController expectOne verify only the api endpoint

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I was would like to only test if request is beiing send to the correct api endpoint. For example: I have a servis that sends request to http://localhost:port/sth/sth2 and i want to chcek only if there was http://localhost:port. I'm using HttpTestingController and expectOne function,  is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you were looking to do?

Setup

```
let httpClient: HttpClient;
let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ]
  });

  httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
  httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
});
```

Test

```
it('can test HttpClient.get', () => {
  const testData: Data = {name: 'Test Data'};

  httpClient.get<Data>('http://localhost:8085/test/suite')
    .subscribe(data =>
      expect(data).toEqual(testData)
    );

  const request = httpTestingController.expectOne(
    (req: HttpRequest<any>) => req.url.includes('http://localhost:8085'));

  request.flush(testData);
  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

It's the example from Angular's documentation, except you pass a function to `expectOne`, that takes a req and returns a boolean that checks if the url of the request contains the right endpoint.

Of course, you'll swap out the HttpClient with your service.

Comment: Oh, yes works fine. I saw docs but im pretty new to Angular and typescript so i didn't know how to pass such a function and couldn't find good example. Anyway thank you.

Comment: No problem :) Angular docs are good, if you ever need to find out what is possible. https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController